# Reuse program in OpenGL on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es-2.0

I have a class, that creates OpenGL programs, attaches shaders and stores id's of these programs in a simple `std::map <std::string, GLuint>.`

*Here is the code of two basic functions of this class:*

```
    GLuint ShaderBuilder::build_shader(GLenum type, const GLchar * shaderStr)
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
        OutputTraceMsg(9, "glCreateShader: %x", glGetError());

        if(shader == 0)
            return 0;

        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderStr, 0);
        OutputTraceMsg(9, "glShaderSource: %x", glGetError());

        glCompileShader(shader);
        OutputTraceMsg(9, "glCompileShader: %x", glGetError());

#ifdef DEBUG
        GLint status = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
        //OutputTraceMsg(9, "glGetShaderiv: %d", glGetError());

        if (status != GL_TRUE)
        {
            GLint logLength;
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
            if (logLength > 0)
            {
                GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
                OutputTraceMsg(1, "Error compiling shader: %s", log);
                free(log);
            }

            glDeleteShader(shader);
            return 0;
        }
#endif
        return shader;
    }

    GLuint ShaderBuilder::create_program(const GLchar * vertexStr, const GLchar * fragmentStr)
    {
        GLuint vertexShader = this->build_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexStr);
        GLuint fragmentShader = this->build_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentStr);

        GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
        if (program == 0)
        {
            OutputTraceMsg(3, "Filter: create program failed");
            return 0;
        }

        glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        glValidateProgram(program);

#ifdef DEBUG
        GLint linked;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
        if(!linked)
        {

            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            if (infoLen > 0)
            {
                char * infoLog = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);
                glGetProgramInfoLog(program, infoLen, &infoLen, infoLog);
                OutputTraceMsg(3, "Error linking program: %s", infoLog);
                free(infoLog);
            }
            glDeleteProgram(program);
            return 0;
        }
#endif

        return program;
    }
```

And I have the following situation : all shaders and programs compiles fine at the initialization step and I successfully fill this std::map with id's of these programs. But after that when I try to use any of these id's with some OpenGL functions like glGetAttribLocation(program, "position") OpenGL returns me GL_INVALID_VALUE. It's strange, because if I in this moment directly call function create_program with same shaders that I used before in my class, glGetAttribLocation(program, "position") returns 0. Also, Instruments tells me to ensure, that program objects were not deleted, but this class is a classic Meyers singleton, so the life time of object of this class must be equal to life time of this program.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure the de-referenced value returned from the `std::map` matches the value of the program object, when created on compilation.
2. Please make sure that you have actually selected the program using `glUseProgram` method before trying to access any uniform/attribute of it.
3. Please also verify that your current GL context is set properly.

   ```
   EAGLContext* context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
   [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
   [context release];
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dereferenced value matches the value of program object, that i've created on initialization step. And i use glUseProgram right after i've got id of the program. It returns GL_INVALID_VALUE too :(

Comment: Are you getting `GL_INVALID_VALUE` when you are creating the program object with `glCreateProgram`?

Comment: No. Context is set properly too. Note: if i call glUseProgram right after i create program - it's fine, return value is 0, but if i try to use this id after the initialization of class is complete in one function i've got same error, in other i've got 0. Between these functions there is no calls to OpenGL ES and they follow one by one.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to point out. A program handle should never be 0 for a valid program, if the program is linked successfully.

Comment: Program handler isn't zero. I mean, that return value of glError(), that i place right after glUseProgram() is zero, if i call this glUseProgram() right after i create this program. But if the initialization of the object of ShaderBuilder class is complete and i try to get and use this program handler from object of my class ShaderBuilder i get the right handler, but glError() after glUseProgram() returns GL_INVALID_VALUE.